# get_cookies() returns empty list with Whatsapp web using Chrome in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, cookies, whatsapp

I am trying to save my cookies for Whatsapp so I can run my program without having to scan a QR code every time.

when using the following code, cookies returns an empty list after logging into Whatsapp

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')

time.sleep(10) #give me enough time to scan the QR code

cookies = browser.get_cookies()
print cookies
```

I am at a loss as to why the cookies that should exist don't show up. (cookies for google.com do show up.)

In this case, I can't use a user-data-dir argument as I am going to run this headlessly, any other suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your session would be stored on google-chrome by-default once you login, you can use user-data to import the same settings and cookies. This won't require you to login again.

[chrome-user-path](https://www.howtogeek.com/255653/how-to-find-your-chrome-profile-folder-on-windows-mac-and-linux/) template ** C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default**

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(user_profile_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome( executable_path="chromedriver", chrome_options=options)
driver.get( "https://api.WhatsApp.com/send?phone={}".format(phone_number))
```

This works for me, you can checkout this [repo](https://github.com/Aqua-4/Auto_WhatsApp/blob/master/whatsapp_utils.py) as well, code is a little outdated but will for fine with a few tweaks